# how to set the dayTimePicker to the present day when the program run (c#)?

Tags: c#, datetimepicker

How do i set the dayTimePicker default value to the date when i run the program (present day)?

Comment: Doesn't it default to the current day anyways?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for current time and date

```
dateTimePicker.Value = DateTime.Now;
```

for current date

```
dateTimePicker.Value = DateTime.Today;
```

Answer (score 2):

You can explicitly set the [`Value`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datetimepicker.value.aspx) property of the control to [`DateTime.Today`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.today.aspx).

```
myPicker.Value = DateTime.Today;
```

However, this is not needed - as the MSDN page mentions:

> If the Value property has not been changed in code or by the user, it is set to the current date and time (DateTime.Now).

Answer (score 0):

```
datetimepicker.value = DateTime.Now;
```

Answer (score 0):

You should do this:

```
yourDateTimePicker.Value = DateTime.Today;
```

Comment: `DateTime.Today` is a property, not a function.

Answer (score 0):

The default value of the control is Today

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datetimepicker.value.aspx):

> If the Value property has not been changed in code or by the user, it is set to the current date and time ([DateTime.Now](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.now.aspx)).